# How can i add two buttons to the listview from the adapter?

Tags: java, android

1.Im very new to programming and this project ask me to have two buttons to initialize maps and make a phone call in this listview

2.Im trying with an if but i don't know too much, please help

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    //variables
    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<Modeldoc> modellist;
    ArrayList<Modeldoc> arrayList;

    //constructor
    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<Modeldoc> modellist) {
        mContext = context;
        this.modellist = modellist;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.arrayList = new ArrayList<Modeldoc>();
        this.arrayList.addAll(modellist);
    }

    public class ViewHolder{
        TextView mTitleTv, mDescTv, mDirTv, mNumTv, mZonTv;
        ImageView mIconIv;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return modellist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return modellist.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int postition, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view==null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowdoct, null);

            //locate the views in rowdoct.xml
            holder.mTitleTv = view.findViewById(R.id.mainTitle);
            holder.mDescTv = view.findViewById(R.id.mainDesc);
            holder.mDirTv = view.findViewById(R.id.mainDir);
            holder.mNumTv = view.findViewById(R.id.mainNum);
            holder.mZonTv = view.findViewById(R.id.mainZon);
            holder.mIconIv = view.findViewById(R.id.mainIcon);

            view.setTag(holder);

        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        }
        //set the results into textviews
        holder.mTitleTv.setText(modellist.get(postition).getTitle());
        holder.mDescTv.setText(modellist.get(postition).getDesc());
        holder.mDirTv.setText(modellist.get(postition).getDir());
        holder.mNumTv.setText(modellist.get(postition).getNum());
        holder.mZonTv.setText(modellist.get(postition).getZon());
        //set the result in imageview
        holder.mIconIv.setImageResource(modellist.get(postition).getIcon());

        //listview item clicks
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //code later
                if (modellist.get(postition).getTitle().equals("Dr. Lorgio Rivera Calvo")){
                    //1

                    if (view.getId() == R.id.mainZon) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:69777300"));
                        mContext.startActivity(intent);
                    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.mainTitle) {
                        Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=-16.5418275,-68.0795961&avoid=tf");
                        Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
                        mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                        mContext.startActivity(mapIntent);
                    }

                }
                if (modellist.get(postition).getTitle().equals("Dr. Jorge Salazar")){
                    //2
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:69777300"));
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
                if (modellist.get(postition).getTitle().equals("Dr. Kurt Gonzalo Paulsen Sandi")){
                    //3
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:22114333"));
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });


        return view;
    }

    //filter
    public void filter(String charText){
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        modellist.clear();
        if (charText.length()==0){
            modellist.addAll(arrayList);
        }
        else {
            for (Modeldoc modeldoc : arrayList){
                if (modeldoc.getTitle().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(charText)){
                    modellist.add(modeldoc);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

---

3. This is my xml model, this goes to my list view in a different activity

   ```
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:layout_margin="16dp">

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:gravity="center_vertical">

   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/mainIcon"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
       android:layout_width="60dp"
       android:layout_height="60dp"
       android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
       android:clickable="true"
       android:onClick="onClick"/>
       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
           android:layout_marginStart="5dp">
           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/mainTitle"
               android:text="Title"
               android:textStyle="bold"
               android:textSize="20sp"
               android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/mainDesc"
               android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
               android:text="Description"
               android:textSize="16sp"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
       </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/mainDir"
       android:text="Dirección"
       android:textSize="16sp"
       android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
       android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/mainNum"
       android:text="0000000"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       android:textSize="12sp"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
       android:paddingBottom="8dp"/>

   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <TextView
           android:paddingTop="10dp"
           android:id="@+id/mainZon"
           android:text="SUR · Calacoto"
           android:textSize="12sp"
           android:textStyle="bold"
           android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

   <Button
       android:layout_alignEnd="@id/mainZon"
       android:layout_width="80dp"
       android:layout_height="40dp"
       android:text="LLAMAR"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       android:background="#E9E9E9"
       android:textColor="#E91E63"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
       android:clickable="true"
       android:onClick="onClick"/>
   </RelativeLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
   ```
4. Ive tried to use an If and Cases but i don't know if im implementing in the right way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ListViews, there are two layout files used.  One specifies the layout for the list as a whole, the other specifies the layout for the list_item.

List Item Layout:
    list_item.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/contact_phone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.73"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:textSize="16sp" 
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/do_phone"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/call"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        />
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/do_map"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/map"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Then, the applicable code in the adapter is this:

ListAdapter.java

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
            context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
}

Button btnCall = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.do_phone);
btnCall.setTag(position);
btnCall.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Integer position = (Integer)v.getTag();
        // This calls a method back in the fragment or activity that owns the adapter
        fragment.callItemList(position);
    }
});

Button btnMap = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.do_map);
btnMap.setTag(position);
btnMap.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Integer position = (Integer)v.getTag();
        // This calls a method back in the fragment or activity that owns the adapter
        fragment.mapItemList(position);
    }
});

TextView txtContactPhone = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_phone); 

return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't figure out where to implement this code, i can share the rest and can you guide me please

Comment: i dont know how to solve the fragment part, the rest is working fine

Comment: In my example, I want to call a public function in the code that declared the Adapter when a button is clicked.  To do that, I needed a reference to that code, which in my case, was in a fragment.  In your case, it might be your Action that created the Adapter.  So, maybe you would have code like this:

    ArrayList<Modeldoc> arrayList;
    Action myAction;

    //constructor
    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<Modeldoc> modellist, Action theAction) {
        mContext = context;
        myAction = theAction;

Answer (score 0):

This is the rest of the code, Activity where I'm implementing this

```
class Medico extends AppCompatActivity {

private Spinner spinner;

ListView listView;
ListViewAdapter adapter;
String[] title;
String[] description;
String[] direccion;
String[] numero;
String[] zona;
int[] icon;
ArrayList<Modeldoc> arrayList = new ArrayList<Modeldoc>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_medico);

    spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    List<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();
    categories.add(0,"Filtrar por especialidad");
    categories.add("Alergología");
    categories.add("Cardiología");

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;
    dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, categories);

    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {
            if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("Filtrar por especialidad"))
            {

            } else
            {
                String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),"Ver:"+item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("Alergología"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent( Medico.this, Alergologia.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

                if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("Cardiología"))
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent( Medico.this, Cardiologia.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });



    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("Médicos");

    title = new String[]{
            "Dr. Jorge Salazar",
            "Dr. Kurt Gonzalo Paulsen Sandi",
            "Dr. Oswaldo Camberos B."};
    description = new String[]{
            " Pediatra - Terapia Intensiva",
            " Pediatra",
            " Pediatra - Neonatólogo - Terapia Intensiva"};
    direccion = new String[]{" Av. 6 de Agosto esq. Cordero, Edif. Mercurio - mezzanine Of. 2 ",
            "Calle Clavijo entre Av.Arce y Av. 6 de Agosto. Edificio San Patricio # 2896. Primer piso consultorio 111.",
            "Calle Clavijo entre Av.Arce y Av. 6 de Agosto. Edificio San Patricio # 2896. Primer piso consultorio 111."};
    numero = new String[]{
            "69777300",
            "22114333",
            "22792635"};
    zona = new String[]{
            "SUR · Calacoto",
            "SUR . Calacoto ",
            "SUR · Calacoto"};
    icon = new int[]{R.drawable.ic_doctora, R.drawable.ic_vacio, R.drawable.ic_doctora};

    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

    for (int i =0; i<title.length; i++){
        Modeldoc modeldoc = new Modeldoc(title[i], description[i], direccion[i], numero[i], zona[i], icon[i]);
        //bind all strings in an array
        arrayList.add(modeldoc);
    }

    //pass results to listViewAdapter class
    adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, arrayList);

    //bind the adapter to the listview
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    MenuItem myActionMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView)myActionMenuItem.getActionView ();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(s)){
                adapter.filter("");
                listView.clearTextFilter();
            }
            else {
                adapter.filter(s);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
}
```

This is the model activity_medico where the list is implemented

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
    tools:context=".Medico">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/covertop"/>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="#B3FFFFFF">

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/searchbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </RelativeLayout>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="40dp"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/design_default_color_background">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"/>

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/spacer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.8dp"
        android:background="#7A7A7A"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp">

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```